# Como utilizar a classe vector do C++?

Tags: c++, vector

Necessariamente precisa da biblioteca `#include<vector.h>`

Para cria-lo

```
vector <int> c;
```

Pergunta: Como armazenar valores nele e lê-los?

Comment: Não conheço muito sobre a linguagem, mas da uma olhada aqui: https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C%2B%2B/Vetores

Comment: Por favor, não leve a mal este comentário, mas quando alguém que ainda está aprendendo a usar um recurso X começa uma pergunta com "necessariamente preciso de X", eu enxergo aí um belo começo de dogma. Cuidado, ok? Vetores têm suas utilidades, mas não são a única e/ou melhor estrutura de dados para toda e qualquer situação.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para essas coisas é sempre interessante consultar a [documentação quase oficial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) e aí fazer perguntas mais específicas do que não entendeu com um exemplo real do que está fazendo.

Uma das muitas formas seria:

```
vector <int> c { 1, 2, 3 }; //inicializa
c.push_back(4); //adiciona
cout << c[2]; //pega o elemento
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/Basic.cpp).

Buscas e outras operações são feitas em [algoritmos gerais](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) para qualquer coleção de dados.

[Documentação alternativa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).

Answer (score 5):

Como descrito na documentação http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

para colocar valores dentro do vector você deve utilizar push_back(valor) e para pegar um valor pode usar o operador [] ou a função at.

```
vector <int> c;
c.push_back(3);
c.push_back(4);
int a = c[0] // a recebe o valor 3
int b = c.at(1) // b recebe o valor 4
```

Comment: O site cplusplus.com não é considerado uma boa referẽncia.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520052/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com

Answer (score 3):

Não tem muito segredo, você usar o push_back para adicionar valores, depois pode pegar eles utilizando o indice ou um iterator.

**Exemplo:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<int> vetor;
    int i;

    // INSERINDO 5 VALORES DE 1 A 5  USANDO PUSH_BACK
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      vetor.push_back(i);
   }
    // PEGANDO O TAMANHO DO VETOR
    cout << "Tamanho do Vetor = " << vetor.size() << endl;

    // ACESSANDO OS 5 VALORES DO VETOR PASSANDO PELO INDEX
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      cout << "Valor do vetor [" << i << "] = " << vetor[i] << endl;
   }

   // OU USANDO O ITERATOR PARA ACESSAR OS VALORES.
   vector<int>::iterator v = vetor.begin();
   while( v != vetor.end()) {
      cout << "Valor do vetor = " << *v << endl;
      v++;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no https://ideone.com/LllvB0